# Geometry-||gm proof

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram in which $P$ and $Q$ are the mid points of the sides $AD$ and $BC$ respectively. If $BP$ & $QD$ intersect the diagonal $AC$ at $X$ and $Y$ respectively then prove that $BP$ and $QD$ trisect the diagonal $AC$ at $X$ and $Y$.

Efforts ;
I tried to prove that $DPBQ$ is a parallelogram as follows:
$$AD=BC$$ 
$$2PD=2QB$$ 
$$PD=QB$$
$$Hence, DPBQ is a ||gm$$.

Now, how to get to the required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

After proving that $BP\parallel QD$, you may first consider $\triangle ADY$ and then $\triangle CBX$. In $\triangle ADY$, $AX=XY$ by midpoint theorem. Again, in $\triangle CBX$, $CY=XY$. Hence $BP$ and $QD$ trisect $AC$ at $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** An alternate approach would be to let the two diagonals intersect at *Z*, and then to notice that the triangles *XAB* and *XPZ* are similar, and that the same holds for triangles *YCD* and *YQZ*. Since *BD* halves *PQ*, and the latter is parallel and equal to both *AB* and *CD*, the result immediately follows.